# Sidekiq: NoMethodError: undefined method `perform'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
2.1.2 :001 > UpdateStyleRanks.perform_async
```

Here is the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `perform' for #<UpdateStyleRanks:0x00000002f5e388>
```

Here is my worker:

```
# app/workers/update_style_ranks.rb
class UpdateStyleRanks
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no naming requirement for workers.  You can do this:

```
class Foo
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform; end
end
```

I suspect you just need to restart Rails/Spring/Zeus to pick up the new class.

Answer (score 0):

How would one restart a heroku dyno running in background?

`heroku run:detached bundle exec sidekiq -e production`

Would the following commands force sidekiq to pickup new class?

`heroku ps:stop run`

`heroku run:detached bundle exec sidekiq -e production`

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of sidekiq (4 and 5) I believe the solution is to call perform_async and not perform.

Answer (score -2):

You should rename you the file to update_style_rank_worker.rb
and the class name to UpdateStyleRankWorker

Comment: Maybe not to fix the problem but it is good coding style right?